# Javascript to show/hide text input border

Tags: javascript, html, border, textinput

Sorry for the really basic/simple question, I'm very new to front end web development.

I've looked at lots of the questions about using Javascript to show/hide things on a web page but none of them talk about specifically showing/hiding a text input border.

On my page I have a text input and a button.

When the page loads I don't want the text input border to be visible.

When the button is clicked I want it to change the state of the text input border (IE: if the text input border is not showing when the button is clicked then it calls a javascript function to make the text input border visible. If the text input border is visible then the javascript function the button calls would make the text input border invisible.)

Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Input Border test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="address1" value="test text input" class="question-text" size=30> 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="showBorder()">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showBorder () {
            var myInput = document.getElementById("address1").style;
            myInput.borderStyle="solid";
        }
    </script>
    <style scoped lang="scss">
        .question-text {
            border: 0;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

When the button is clicked there are no visible changes to the text input border or the page in general for that matter.

Any direction would be much appreciated, I'll be sure to upvote any help and mark the most applicable answer as accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Input Border test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="address1" value="test text input" class="question-text" size=30> 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="toggleBorder()">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleBorder () {
            var myInput = document.getElementById("address1");
            myInput.classList.toggle('question-text-border');
        }
    </script>
    <style scoped lang="scss">
        .question-text {
            border: 0;
        }
        .question-text-border {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

- `classList` is basically an array with a few special functions: [Class List Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- calling toggle on class list removes the class if present and adds it if absent
- The bottom css class `.question-text-border` overrides the class `.question-text`

Let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.

Comment: simple, right to the point, code explained, worked exactly as expected = upvote and marked as accepted answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[Border](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) requires three parts.  The size, defined in almost anything, i.e. 2px, the type of line, such as dotted or solid, and the color, such as mediumspringgreen (the best green).  So, in order to properly use the border property, you need to set the border in JavaScript by using the three afore mentioned properties.  Instead of `myInput.borderStyle="solid";`, you should use `myInput.borderStyle="1px solid crimson";`, or whichever other values you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a size also..
Just add this..

myInput.borderStyle="solid";
myInput.borderWidth= '1px'

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your style border none, check for a border of null, and the use .style.border to set the border to the border you want:

```js
//
var myInput = document.getElementById("address1");
//
function showBorder() {
  if (myInput.style.border == "") {
    myInput.style.border = "1px solid black";
  } else {
    myInput.style.border = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.question-text {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="address1" value="test text input" class="question-text" size=30>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="showBorder()">
```

Comment: code works, loved the inclusion of "Run code snippet", upvoted